# SendInput on c++ doesn't take Ctrl and Shift in account

Tags: c++, winapi, sendinput

I'm trying to send a  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> key stroke to a control, in a C++ application written with Embarcadero. I'm using the code below:

```
tagINPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

// Appui sur Ctrl
ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Appui sur Shift
ip.ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Appui sur End
ip.ki.wVk = VK_END;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

Application->ProcessMessages();

// Relacher End
ip.ki.wVk = VK_END;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Relacher Shift
ip.ki.wVk = VK_SHIFT;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Relacher Ctrl
ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

However, it appears to be working like if there was no action on the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> keys.

What am I missing ?

Comment: sendinput is not part of the standard c++, you should include more tags to your question, if you leave it like this you should include the code to that sendinput function, but I am guessing that you don´t have it, not everyone that uses c++ uses Embarcadero.

Comment: To be honest, I'm using the SendInput that was coming from theproject, enclosed in a win32.h file. This was done by someone else that is no longer in my company, so I cannot give any accurate idea of what it does.

Comment: It's used for synthesizing keystrokes

Comment: Ok, this I got it. Now, why does it synthesize keystrokes as if the Ctrl and Shift were not hit, despite the SendInput I wrote in the code included in my question ?

Comment: Look for other examples here on SO for how to do this properly. I know there are some, but I don't have time to do your search for you right now. Search for `SendInput`.

Comment: You should not do multiple `SendInput()` calls but instead pass an array with all the input you want to send in a **single** `SendInput()` call.

Comment: I will try it, I thought about it. However some other bugs are keeping me away from that solution. Tomorrow is another day.

Comment: It's really important that you put all the events in an array and make one call to SendInput

Comment: Does important mean mandatory ? I mean: could that be the actual reason for it does not work ? Kinda odd behaviour for SendInput...

Comment: You can do it wrong if you want. The documentation explains the consequences of doing it wrong.

Comment: Well, I tried using an array of tagINPUT and one single SendInput, and the result is exactly the same as previously: the form reacts like if only the END key was hit.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that the `VK_END` key is an extended key. So you should declare this in the flags:

```
eip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
ip.ki.wVk = VK_END;
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
ip.ki.dwFlags = ip.ki.dwFlags | 1;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

Application->ProcessMessages();

// Relacher End
ip.ki.wVk = VK_END;
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
ip.ki.dwFlags = ip.ki.dwFlags | 1;
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Note that I used 1 for setting the flag as I don't know if you have a constant defined in your C++, but assume there is a constant someplace.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I bet this is exactly the answer I needed :) I'll try it out quite soon and will tell wether it works or not (it surely well, I think).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` flag to `dwFlags`

```
input.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY;
```

Unfortunately, Win32 doesn't provide any way to determine if a key is extended. Here I just used a vector

```
    extended_keys << VK_INSERT;
    extended_keys << VK_DELETE;
    extended_keys << VK_HOME;
    extended_keys << VK_END;
    extended_keys << VK_PRIOR;
    extended_keys << VK_NEXT;
    extended_keys << VK_LEFT;
    extended_keys << VK_UP;
    extended_keys << VK_DOWN;
    extended_keys << VK_RIGHT;
```

and checked if it's inside the list add the flag